# No match for operator != (operands types are pointer and object)

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, operator-overloading, this

I'm overloading both `==` and `!=` operators and want the latter to refer to the former in order to not repeat any code at all. This is what I have written:

```cpp
bool Date :: operator == (const Date & other) const {
    bool are_equal = Year() == other.Year();

    for (int i=0; i<other.NumEvents() && are_equal; i++)
        are_equal = this[i] == other[i];

    return are_equal;
}

bool Date :: operator != (const Date & other) const {
    return !(this == other);
}
```

The big problem here is that `this` is not a `Date` but a `Date*`. Is there a way to refer to `this Date` without a pointer or using `this` along with `other Date`?

Comment: Also `this[i] == other[i]` almost certainly does not correctly compare `*this` and `other` for equality.

Comment: @Yunnosch -  That's true.  But it is certainly comparing a `Date`  with (a reference) to something that is probably not a `Date`.    Unless the class `Date` is rather unusual (e.g. has an `operator[](int)` that returns a `Date`) then the compiler will be diagnosing that too.    The OP is clearly just reading the last error message from the compiler - and when the problem asked about is fixed, will probably come back asking a similar question about the "new" error message.

Comment: @Peter I agree (and did agree), I probably should have phrased "True. And ...". But by now I spotted the condition I missed....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dereference the pointer:

```
return !(*this == other);
```

Comment: See the comments on the question for hints on other issues with your code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to dereference the `this` pointer in order to invoke your operators on the `Date` object it refers to, eg:

```
bool Date :: operator == (const Date & other) const {
    bool are_equal = ((Year() == other.Year()) && (NumEvents() == other.NumEvents()));

    for (int i = 0; (i < other.NumEvents()) && are_equal; ++i) {
        are_equal = ((*this)[i] == other[i]);
    }

    return are_equal;
}

bool Date :: operator != (const Date & other) const {
    return !((*this) == other);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to overload `!=` function like this:

```
bool Date :: operator != (const Date & other) const {
    return !(*this == other);
}
```